# Setting up visual studio application to use MongoDB

Tags: c#, android, mongodb, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I'm going to use Xamarin to make an Android app for college.
I'd also like to use MongoDB as I want to get a feel for a non-RDBMS.

With that in mind, i've been using this guide to help me with a very simple setup
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/093731/xamarin-with-mongodb/

It's from August, 2015 so i'd be surprised if it's not up-to-date.
The problem i'm running into is that on Step 1 of the code instructions, I am getting an error on the following line:

```
var con = new MongoConnectionStringBuilder("server=127.0.0.1;database=galary");
```

which states that

```
The type or namespace name 'MongoConnectionStringBuilder' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Does anybody with experience in this have any idea if there's something extra which I need to install, or is there a nuget package that i'm missing? Perhaps the author accidentally left it out.

Comment: are you doing this in the server project, or the Xamarin project?

Comment: Did you add a reference to `MongoDB` in your project?

Comment: Your MongoDB will be in WebAPI project anyways, so I'd suggest you to go with the official documentation for .NET Driver:
e.g. https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/client/ and
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/